# How to prevent external HID scanner Scan in Textfield value continues in a row

Tags: swiftui

I have an SearchBar textfield act as first responder which is working fine. But when I used HID scanner (like external keyboard) to scan barcode in first attempt scan work but when scan other barcode or the same barcode it add to last scan.

**What I see:**

1. first scan (1234)
2. second scan (12341234) the same barcode scan twice it add to last.

**What I expect:**

1. first scan (1234)
2. second scan (1234) the same barcode scan and if other barcode it replace current barcode from textfield

**This is my firstresponder**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
@StateObject var itemVM = ProductViewListModel()
@Binding var text: String
var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void

class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, onTextChanged: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        _text = text
        self.onTextChanged = onTextChanged
        
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        text =  String("\(searchText)")
      // text = removeDuplicates(in: searchText)
        //onTextChanged(text)
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.reload(_:)), object: searchBar)
        perform(#selector(self.reload(_:)), with: searchBar, afterDelay: 0.75)
    
    }
    @objc func reload(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    
        guard let query = searchBar.text, query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) != "" else {
            print("nothing to search")
            return
        }
       print(query)
        
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $text, onTextChanged: onTextChanged)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
    searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    return searchBar
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
    uiView.text = text
    uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
   } 
 }
```

Parent View:

```
struct ShowItemList: View {
@StateObject       var itemVM = ProductViewListModel()
@EnvironmentObject var order:  OrderViewModel
@State var searchtext = ""
@State var isHidden = true

var body: some View {
    SearchBar(text: $searchtext, onTextChanged: addSelect)
    .opacity(isHidden ? 0 : 1)
    ItemListHeader() // Header sa Item List
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(itemVM.item.filter({searchtext.isEmpty ? true : $0.sku.contains(searchtext) || $0.label.lowercased().contains(searchtext)}))
        { dataPoint in
        //ForEach(itemVM.item) { dataPoint in
        ZStack{
            HStack{
                Text(dataPoint.label)
                    .frame(width:220, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
                    .padding(.leading,30)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(dataPoint.price)")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
                Spacer()
                Text("\(dataPoint.quantity)")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
            }
            .padding(.leading, -20)
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            .padding(.bottom, 5)
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.order.AddToCart(item: dataPoint.product)
        }.alert(isPresented: $order.isValid) {
            Alert(title: Text("Not enough stocks remaining"), message: Text("Adjust item or PO item"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
            Divider()
        }
      }
    .onAppear(perform: itemVM.fetchProduct)
    .padding()
   }

  func addSelect(for searchtext: String) {
       if !searchtext.isEmpty {
       // itemVM.searchItem(searchItem: searchtext)
       // self.order.AddToCart(item: self.itemVM.item[0].product)
        print($searchtext)

       }
   }
  }

extension View {
 func hidden(_ shouldHide: Bool) -> some View {
    opacity(shouldHide ? 0 : 1)
  }
}

struct ProductsListContainer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ProductsListContainer()
   }
 }
```

hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: In the parent view, before you call `SearchBar`, or after you have process the first scan,
set the `text = ""`

Comment: @workingdog I have already added. You can check my parent view

Comment: @workingdog do you have any idea how to achieve my issue?  I have spending 2 weeks already. Thank you

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't understand your question here. I'm not familiar with using 
external scanning devices. You mention scanning barcode problems, but you just show some code regarding 
a SearchBar. I don't see the relevance to multiple scanning.

Comment: @workingdog sorry if my questions is not clear.  my issue is more on textfield. external HID scanner  when scan barcode twice or other barcode it add on the next value of textfield instead should replace for new barcode. Sorry for bad english

Comment: as you say, the problem is when you scan twice, so show us the code where you scan.